# i9 9900k overheating in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Does anyone have a similar issue? I have a i9 9900k cpu stock with a Dark Rock 4 cooler. While rendering the temperatures rise to 100C and it begins throttling. Blender is the only software on my pc that can reach this temperature.

I believe the cooler is quite capable of cooling this cpu, so why does overheating happen in blender only?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Because Blender is probably the only software you tried that uses all cores on the CPU. Try Cinebench, Aida64, etc. you will see the same issue. It's a hardware issue. Check if your cooler is properly seated, if the thermalpaste is not a problem, and make sure your pc case is not one of those closed of stylish garbage ones with no air circulation.

Comment: Under the performance section in the render tab you can change the number of threads Cycles uses. Check task manager while you're doing the render and see how much stress your CPU is under

Comment: @Steve That helps the overheating issue. By setting it to 1 from default 5. The render time is increased 5 times, obviously.

Comment: Yes, though that would be a bad idea. changing it from the number of cores you have to the number of cores you have -1 to see if it's still a problem would be a more reasonable option. Hopefully this is not an issue any more in Blender 2.9 or 3.0 . Would be interesting to see if the OP still has the problem.